# Optimizing Windows Service for sending HTTP requests

Tags: c#, multithreading, optimization, windows-services, threadpool

The application that I'm writing sends SMS messages that are stored in databases. For this portion, I'm writing a windows service that will go through a selection of databases and then send the waiting messages as HTTP requests.

Because the application is sending SMS, speed is important. Right now, I'm only getting about 15 requests sent per second. Right now, the application creates `SMSMessages` and then puts them in a synchronized queue. I use multithreading to run 20 threads at a time from that queue.

I noticed that if I ran too many threads then the application actually slowed down the number of messages sent per second.

What I'm trying to figure out is if there is a faster way than what I'm doing to send the requests. Is there a better way to organize my threads, or should I use threadpooling or asynchronous requests to optimize the application?

The main code is here:

```
            Queue Messages = new Queue();
            DataRow[] Rows = dtSMSCombined.Select(); //Created from a datatable
            foreach (DataRow Row in Rows)
            {
                ... //Get information from the row.

                SMSMessage oSMS = new SMSMessage(Keyword, Number, Message, MessageID);
                Messages.Enqueue(oSMS);
            }

            Queue SyncedMessages = Queue.Synchronized(Messages);
            var tasks = new Task[20];

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    { //each thread will pull out new items from the queue as they finish
                        while (SyncedMessages.Count > 0)
                        {
                            Response = new XDocument();
                            SMSMessage oSMS = (SMSMessage)SyncedMessages.Dequeue();

                            if (oSMS.GetMessage() != null && oSMS.GetMessage() != string.Empty)
                            {
                                Response = oSMS.SendSMS();
                            }
                            string ResponseCode = (string)Response.Descendants("response").First();
                            if (ResponseCode == "ok")
                            {
                                oSMS.sResponseCode = ResponseCode;
                                oSMS.dCompleted = DateTime.Now;
                            }
                            else { }

                            oSMS.DTInsert();
                        }
                    });
            }

            while (tasks.Any(t => !t.IsCompleted)) { }
```

Here is the `SendSMS()` method from the `SMSMessage` class:

```
    public XDocument SendSMS()
    {
        XML = "<message id=\""+ lMessageID +"\"><partnerpassword>" + PartnerPassword + "</partnerpassword><content>" + sMessage + "</content></message>";
        URL = "http://sloocetech.net:****/spi-war/spi/" + PartnerID + "/" + sRecipient + "/" + Keyword + "/messages/mt";
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        Request.Proxy = null;

        RequestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XML);
        Request.Method = "POST";
        Request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
        Request.ContentLength = RequestBytes.Length;
        RequestStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
        RequestStream.Write(RequestBytes, 0, RequestBytes.Length);
        RequestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse Resp = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
        oReader = new StreamReader(Resp.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        string backstr = oReader.ReadToEnd();

        oReader.Close();
        Resp.Close();

        Doc = XDocument.Parse(backstr);
        return Doc;
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it possible for the API to allow you to send a bulk of messages?

Comment: Is there a bulk sending method? They do not have one listed in their API.

Comment: This busy waiting is unnecessary (`while (tasks.Any(t => !t.IsCompleted)) { }`). You can use `Task.WaitAll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And what if you reuse the

```
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
```

object?

The connection parameters do not change between calls. Do you think it could be a good idea to make it a static field?

**[EDIT]**

For example, you define `Request` as a static field:

```
static HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
```

Or, even a dictionary of `Request objects:

```
static Dictionary<string,HttpWebRequest> Requests = new Dictionary<string,HttpWebRequest>();
```

Then, in your `SendSMS()` method:

```
public XDocument SendSMS()
{
    XML = "<message id=\"" + lMessageID + "\"><partnerpassword>" + PartnerPassword + "</partnerpassword><content>" + sMessage + "</content></message>";
    URL = "http://sloocetech.net:****/spi-war/spi/" + PartnerID + "/" + sRecipient + "/" + Keyword + "/messages/mt";

    //check if the request object exists
    if (!Requests.Keys.Contains(sRecipient))
        Requests.Add((HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL));

    //get the existing request from the dictionary
    Requests = Requests[sRecipient];

    //configure the request
    Request.Proxy = null;
    RequestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XML);
    Request.Method = "POST";
    Request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
    Request.ContentLength = RequestBytes.Length;
    RequestStream = Request.
    RequestStream.Write(RequestBytes, 0, RequestBytes.Length);
    RequestStream.Close();

    using (System.IO.Stream RequestStream = Request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (WebResponse response = Request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (oReader = new StreamReader(Resp.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default))
            {
                string backstr = oReader.ReadToEnd();
                Doc = XDocument.Parse(backstr);
            }
        }
    }

    return Doc;
}
```

**[EDIT]**

Maybe you should also play a litle with the following static field:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20;
```

Comment: Part of creating a new connection each time was that this will cycle through a series of databases with potentially different keywords and different recipients. What advantage does creating a dictionary of connections create?

Comment: In this case, the `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20` solved the problem. I rewrote the rest, but that fixed a major bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

The kind of busy-waiting that you are doing is really burning a lot of CPU.

```
while (tasks.Any(t => !t.IsCompleted)) { }
```

Actually, I don't understand how your code runs at all without exceptions because you check the count and then deque. But multiple threads might find the count to be one and all try to dequeue. All but one of them would be failing.

I think you should start to learn the basics of multi-threading now before you proceed. Any concrete advice would probably not help much because the code is so ridden with bugs (there are others than the two I mentioned). Try to find a good tutorial on "fork join parallelism with .net" and find out what features are provided by the TPL.

It is important to understand how multiple threads can cooperate safely and not trample over each others data.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was asking for, I'm not familiar with threading.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `Queue` use for example a `ConcurrentQueue` - for details see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287108.aspx). It is a thread-safe implementation and mostly lock-free thus very fast...